# Surface area of $y = \sin(\pi x)$, from $x=0$ to $2$, rotated about the $x$-axis.

Tags: integration, volume, area

When I use the surface area formula I get 0, and Wolfram got zero as well when I use the bounds 0 to 2, why is this? However the solution manual uses the integral with bounds 0 to 1.. What is going on?!

Comment: How are you calculating the surface area? And what are you plugging into Wolfram? Your question is lacking in detail, so it's hard to say exactly what's going on.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza, OP is trying to find the area of the surface generated by rotating the sine wave about the $x$-axis, not just the area between the axis and the function (which is what would be given by your absolute value suggestion). They should have a look at [surfaces of revolution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SurfaceofRevolution.html) if they are unsure how to proceed.

Comment: @DivergentQueries, oops, my comment is useless

Comment: $$S=2\pi\int_0^2 |f(x)|\sqrt{1+f'^2(x)}\,dx$$. May be you forget $|f(x)|$?

Comment: Is this correct? @MichaelGaluza http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2pi+*+integral+0+to+2+of+%28%28sinpix%29sqrt%281%2Bpi%5E2cospi%5E2x%29%29

Comment: 2pi * integral 0 to 2 of ((sinpix)sqrt(1+pi^2cospi^2x))

Comment: Why is there an absolute value on f(x) in your equation @MichaelGaluza, in my formula sheet it says 2pi*y*sqrt(1+(dy/dx)^2)

Comment: I would really like to see how you got $0$.

Comment: @Munt, surface must be positive. Radius of section is $|f(x)|$, isn't it?

Comment: @MichaelGaluza, How do i make that integral positive. I fixed my integral and got the number posted in the wolfram alpha link i posted. It is a negative number. Can i just absolute value that number or...?

Comment: @Munt, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Surface area of $y=\sin(\pi x)$ from $x=0$ to $2$, rotated about the $x$-axis, is
$$S = 2\pi\int_0^2 |\sin(\pi x)|\sqrt{1+(\sin(\pi x))'^2}\,dx$$
Using WA (see [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5Cpi+%5Cint_0%5E2+%7C%5Csin%28%5Cpi+x%29%7C%5Csqrt%7B1%2B%28%5Csin%28%5Cpi+x%29%29%27%5E2%7D%5C%2Cdx)), we obtain
$$S = 4\sqrt{1+\pi^2} + \frac{4}{\pi}\ln{(\pi+\sqrt{1+\pi^2})}$$

Since $|\sin(\pi(1+x))|=|\sin(\pi x)|$, you can integrate from $0$ to $1$ and double result.

Comment: The answer in my book is 2sqrt(1-pi^2) + 2/pi * ln(pi + sqrt(1+pi^2)), is that the same as what you wrote?

Comment: @Munt, if you assummed $2\sqrt{1+\pi^2}$, not $2\sqrt{1-\pi^2}$, then your answer is a half. Are you sure that you don't need multiply by 2 (see above why)?

Comment: No I mean the answer to the problem you solved was the one I commented above. I am wondering whether my professor made a mistake, or did you compute incorrectly? Thanks for your help by the way

Comment: Furthermore How do i compute without wolfram the |sinpix| portion of the integral? Not sure how I would do that on a test

Comment: Because without the absolute value, you could let u = pi * cos pix, but now that the absolute value is introduced how do I solve it?

Comment: @Munt, use $ |\sin(\pi(1+x))|=|\sin(\pi x)|$; if $0\le x\le \pi$, $\sin(\pi x) \ge 0$.

Comment: Sorry I really dont understand ...

Comment: what |sin(π(1+x))|=|sin(πx)| really means.. can you explain in words?

Comment: oh yes yes that makes sense I just drew the sin curve and that makes sense. OK so how should i proceed from there, to evaluating the integral?

Comment: Ok so I got it, I will just do it from 0 to 1 then double the result, thanks.

Comment: Can I ask however conceptually, why when I take the integral from 0 to 2, I am getting a negative answer as opposed to doing it from 0 to 1, then multiplying by two?

Comment: @Munt, I don't understand you. Integral without 'abs' is zero; with 'abs' it's positive.

Comment: I mean why cant we just do straight up the integral from 0 to 2, instead of doing it from 0 to 1, then multiplying by two.